# Linking AdMob to Google Play created a new app

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I've created a new app in AdMob dashboard to integrate ads on my Android app before I publish it in Google Play Store and linked it to Firebase as well.

After publishing my app to Google Play Store, I've waited 48 hours for the indexing to be able to link my AdMob to my app in Google Play Store.

[image]

So I linked my app to from Google Play to AdMob but AdMob created a new app instead of actually just linking my existing AdMob app to my Google Play Store app.

[image]

### So my question is

how do I actually just link my existing AdMob app to my Google Play Store App?

I want to avoid recreating all my ad units and re-link everything and publish an update on Google Play Store.

### Follow up questions:

- Does linking your Play Store app to AdMob has always been like this?
- Do I really need to link my Google Play Store app to my AdMob?
- What are the complications / benefits of linking my AdMob to my Google Play Store app?
- What action can you recommend for this situation?

Thank you.